# Remote tab title in Konsole

Tags: ssh, konsole, tabs

I login to remote hosts with small one-line scripts, such as:

r1:
`ssh -C user1@host1`

r2:
`ssh -C user2@host2`

etc. But when I login with these commands, the Konsole tab title is not changed to (user)host, as if I was logged in by typing ssh -C user@host. Is there a way to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: please provide full example of what you tried and what does not work. I suspect that switches `-tt` might do the job, but if you provide different inputs/outputs to these scripts, then there is no way how the remote server could communicate the remote addresses with the local one.

Answer (score 0):

In your script, try to replacing:

```
ssh -C user@host
```

with:

```
exec ssh -C user@host
```

Tried with konsole from kde 5.